# NSSortDescriptor, Get latest 5 record sorted by date

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

For my chat application, I only want to last 5 messages, sorted by date. 
If I set the fetchLimit, the chatMessages is sorted correctly, but I get the first 5 messages sorted by date.

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

 [fetchRequest setFetchLimit:5];
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you try setting ascending:NO in sortDescriptor ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the `ascending` to `NO`,

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

[fetchRequest setFetchLimit:5];
```

Answer (score 3):

Change the `NSSortDescriptor` to `ascending:NO`. Then reverse the order of the resulting `NSArray`.